# Is there a way to change the SQLEXPRESS server to MSSQLSERVER on Microsoft Sql Server Management?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello and thanks for your time!
I'm new using Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio and i want to make a change, i want to change the MySqlExpress server (by default it's showing me on connection time) with MSSQLSERVER --- but i can't find or i don't know how to set to achieve this.

Do you can provide any help, please? I really need, i wanted to make the same thing in Workbench to but without any luck, still pointing on the SQLEXPRESS (even if it's broke...) so i need to use this another server...

Thanks!

Comment: MySql or SQL Server? They're two completly separate programs that use different clients each.

Comment: Are you asking how to upgrade a SQL Server Express instance to a non-express instance? I would, personally, suggest installing a second instance, rather than trying to upgrade an express instance. Then `CREATE` the needed `LOGIN`s on your new instance, and back up and restore the databases from once instance to the other.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answers! @Alejandro SQL Server, my SQLEXPRESS SERVER it's doesn't work, i tried to make something about that for the last 2 days but without any luck... and today i downloaded Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio and with that, i also downloaded a MSSQLSERVER i want to use that here or in Workbench but in neither one i can't find the option to do that, i mean to make a connection db with that server, they still pointed at SQLEXPRESS which is broke... what can i do?

Comment: @Larnu, sorry for being dumb and not knowing how to explain... noo, i don;t want to upgrade Sql Server Express (doesn't work but i installed another one <MS SQL SERVER> and i want to use that, but i find the option just for SQL Express.... and i don't know what can i do

Comment: What I understand is that you have two instances installed of SQL Server and you don't know how to switch between them. Am i right?

Comment: @BilalBinZia yep, i have two different instances installed of SQL Server and i don't know how to choose one instead of another, because in Sql Workbench or Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio when i make a new connection, just the SQL Express Server it's there, and no the other one (MSSQL Server)  even if it's running

Comment: I have answered it for you. check it. This will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to switch between your two or more Installed instances of SQL Server, Simply follow these steps:

1). Click on Connect To Server

2). Click on Server Name DropDown. All instances appear here but if they don't no problem.

[image: Like This]

3). Click on "Browse for more..." and expand "Database Engine"

[image: Database Engine]

4). Choose your desired instance

Comment: Sir, you need to change your name in "life saver"! Thanks a lot for your time and for your help! Have a good weekend!

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hei, sorry for being so annoying, but... you can help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401143/connection-spring-boot-cloud-with-mysql-workbench-in-docker-compose-resulting-in